# Does the size of embedding have a huge influence on the training speed?

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

In my text classification task, I use vectors to represent the words.
After I enlarge the size of vocabulary (word dimension is still 128), from 200000 to 1000000, the training step time arise from 0.1s to 0.4s.
Here is the word embedding tensor creatation:

```
tf.get_variable('embedding', shape, dtype=dtype, return tf.get_variable('embedding', shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1), trainable=True)
```

And the sentences are made of word ids and vectors will be looked up from the embedding tensor above.

```
inputs_embedding = tf.contrib.layers.embedding_lookup_unique(embedding, inputs)
```

So what confused me is that why the size of vocabulary has a significant impact on the training speed. Is that normal ?

Comment: Which optimizer are you using? Some like GradientDescentOptimizer will do completely sparse updates to embedding matrices, whereas some like AdamOptimizer make dense updates to an entire variable (there is a LazyAdam in tf.contrib.opt IIRC that does sparse updates).

Comment: I use adam or rmsprop as optimizer.  You mean I should use sgd or LazyAdam to boost the training speed ?

Comment: Well,  I have tried sgd, lazy_adam to see whether the optimizer affects the training speed. It seems that there is no obvious change.   My experiment is on distribute training on five GPUs, in Asynchronous Update .

Comment: Huh, could be another reason gradients aren't sparse. My next step would be to look at a [timeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide) and figure out which ops are taking more time when the embedding matrix size increases.

Comment: The sparse update for Adam and SGD optimizer might only work on CPU. Sparse update for large embedding is always challenging for GPU. I suggest you try using CPU with distributed training.